# Excel - ASSIGNING PRIORITY

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements

Logically, I have a hierarchal set of strings that looks  like this:

`Priority 1 = "SAME"       <---Most important`

`Priority 2 = "DIFFERENT"`

`Priority 3 = "CLASSICAL"`

`Priority 4 = "DROPPED"    <---Least important`

If I have 5 contiguous Excel cells, with any combination of 1 of the above strings in each cell, I would like to have the sixth cell displaying the highest priority if it exists AT LEAST ONCE. Many combinations can occur, below are a few examples of what I'm trying to achieve with each example depicting 5 contiguous cells with a string in each:

Example 1:

`| DROPPED | DROPPED | CLASSICAL | DROPPED | DROPPED |`

Sixth cell should equal: `| CLASSICAL |` because it is of highest priority which shows up at least once

Example 2:

`| CLASSICAL | DIFFERENT| SAME | DROPPED | DIFFERENT|`

Sixth cell should equal: `| SAME |` because it is of highest priority which shows up at least once

Example 3:

`| DIFFERENT | CLASSICAL |CLASSICAL | DROPPED | DIFFERENT |`

Sixth cell should equal: `| DIFFERENT |`because it is of highest priority which shows up at least once

Comment: Any help towards this is appreciated...thanks!

Comment: @Mitch, is there a way to do this through Access (using a SELECT statement)?

Comment: @Mitch, actually, it's okay, it's not needed in ACCESS...thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your 5 contiguous cells are in columns A through E you can use this formula in cell F:

```
=IF(OR(A1="SAME",B1="SAME",C1="SAME",D1="SAME",E1="SAME"),"SAME",IF(OR(A1="DIFFERENT",B1="DIFFERENT",C1="DIFFERENT",D1="DIFFERENT",E1="DIFFERENT"),"DIFFERENT",IF(OR(A1="CLASSICAL",B1="CLASSICAL",C1="CLASSICAL",D1="CLASSICAL",E1="CLASSICAL"),"CLASSICAL",IF(OR(A1="DROPPED",B1="DROPPED",C1="DROPPED",D1="DROPPED",E1="DROPPED"),"DROPPED","No Match"))))
```

The end of the formula defines what to say if there is no match.  I set it to "No Match" but you can replace that with "" for blank or whatever string you want to see.  You can copy it down as many rows as needed:

[image]

Comment: is there a way to do this through Access (using a SELECT statement)?

Comment: actually, it's okay, it's not needed in ACCESS...thanks again!

Comment: If it was needed in Access I believe it could be done, but sounds like you are ok without it for now!

Comment: Hi @Mitch - it appears that although this works great within Excel, it does look like I'll require a solution in Access / SQL as well. Would you know how this could be done? - Thank you

Comment: To get the best answer I would post it as a new question.  I am not well versed in Access.

Answer (score 2):

If you added the number in front of the string like 
"1 SAME", "2 DIFFERENT" etc , you can use the following array formula

```
 =INDEX(A1:E5,MATCH(MIN(VALUE(LEFT(A1:E5,1))),VALUE(LEFT(A1:E5,1)),0))
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to enter the array formula.

Comment: is there a way to do this through Access (using a SELECT statement)?

Comment: actually, it's okay, it's not needed in ACCESS...thanks again!

Comment: Actually, is it possible to do this solution in Access / SQL? I do in fact need some help on the SQL side - thanks!